# Drill Down by code in PowerBI-JavaScript source code github throwing error

Tags: angularjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

After download the source code from Github as suggested in this community forum, run the application with ng serve -o and also run the commands

`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` but it throws the error like-

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. Error: Local
>   workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. at
>   WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath
>   (RND\PowerBI-JavaScript-master\PowerBI-JavaScript-master\demo\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:37:19)

So, can anyone help me how to run this application

Comment: Could you please show your package.json file?

Comment: This is the github url from where i have downloaded the source code and simple run ng serve -o https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Menu-Commands-Extension

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to use the library for Power BI Embedding and are mistaking it for an angular component library of some sort.

Angular CLI is a library that helps when writing Angular applications, which in this case would probably require you to run `ng init` to create the angular.json and only then running `ng serve`.

Again, not sure what you're trying to do with regards to the linked library (PowerBI-Javascript)